# ExceptionHandler in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, try-catch, cil, mono.cecil

Good day to all!

I copy a method with use of Mono.Cecil, and have faced the following problem:

My function for copying is simple (it's for example):

```
public static bool Ping()
{
   MessageBox.Show("Ping");
   try
   {
       MessageBox.Show("status");
   }
   catch (Exception exception)
   {
       MessageBox.Show("Exception ");
       return false;
   }
   return true;
}
```

It's work not problem. But if I do:

```
MessageBox.Show("Exception " + exception.Message);
```

I have the trouble: when execution reaches the function call, it's generate "Unhandled Exception" and clr finishes work. I can't even see `MessageBox.Show("Ping")`!

I copy try/catch blocks so:

```
    foreach (ExceptionHandler exh in SourceMethod.Body.ExceptionHandlers)
    {
        var ex = new ExceptionHandler(exh.HandlerType)
        {
            TryStart = exh.TryStart,
            TryEnd = exh.TryEnd,
            HandlerStart = exh.TryEnd,
            HandlerEnd = exh.HandlerEnd,
            CatchType = Assembly.MainModule.Import(typeof(Exception)), 
            HandlerType = exh.HandlerType,
            FilterStart = exh.FilterStart
        };
        target.Body.ExceptionHandlers.Add(ex);
   }
```

And I think my problem is here:

```
        CatchType = Assembly.MainModule.Import(typeof(Exception)),
```

But I do not know how to make this properly

I tryed:

```
CatchType = exh.CatchType
```

But unfortunate.

How to solve this situation? Have any ideas?

Comment: Put a nested Try/Catch around `MessageBox.Show("Exception " + exception.Message);` and tell us what the nested exception is

Comment: @JeremyThompson, try/carch is nothing shows, because code execution does not reach inside the method body, when I call `exception.Message`, `exception.GetType()` etc - on the whole any appeal to argument `Exception exception`. It's mean that the exectution of the function doesn't even begin. Therefore I can't catch any exceptions - I can't catch nothing. the only window that appears says that an unexpected unhandled exception error has occurred. I think when the execution reaches the method, the clr can't recognize the msil code inside it as valid and crash

Comment: But the il code if you look through ilspy or ilpsector coincides with the original one. I checked it for sure

Comment: What exactly are you doing? If you are modifying the IL, then you will likely need to update the offsets/lengths of the exception handlers. Also, what is the exception you are getting?

Comment: @BrianReichle, It's right. I know. But I get the error, when I just copy the method like here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mono-cecil/AuccpGwIQC0. Source il-code and target il -code have a match 100% (it's here https://pastebin.com/h21W8yE3 - from Simple Assembler Explorer). I searched for the error for a long time and came to the conclusion that everything depends on whether I use the `exception` variable or not, without any modifications of the il-code

Comment: It's getting harder to understand, can you please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @JeremyThompson, ok. For example I did two projects. I'll post the code on pastebin, because here in the comments it will look in one line, unreadable. It's simple projects: https://pastebin.com/zqg6hqF2 and https://pastebin.com/gBg57n6g. it is enough to create the new console project and to insert a code: the last program copies methods of the 1st program. If to use exception, the mistake takes off. Without him - everything works

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are generating invalid IL and the runtime is detecting that and not even starting to run your program (whence you don't see the **ping**).

You can check that (on Windows at least) by running:

> *peverify path-to-your-assembly*

That being said, you can see a full example here: https://cecilifier.me/?gistid=fd87051cdca0860916a171c419a30f80